# Listen to all (device-wide) touch events in Android

Tags: android, service, touch-event, accessibility

I am working on a background service that runs to give sound feedback device-wide whenever the user is touching the screen. I tried to create an overlay with a custom view to listen to touches and pass them down to the views below in a similar direction to what was attempted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top?lq=1) but my overlay seemed to be either consuming all the touch events or if I returned `false` only the down touch was detected.

I was wondering if there was perhaps an accessibility route I could take? Basically I need a way to get the information of any current touches on the screen (preferably multitouch) I don't need to alter the touch event or anything, just need the information.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible, even with accessibility APIs, except perhaps on rooted devices or with custom ROMs.

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct. This is intentionally not something that apps are able to do on stock Android.